# PHP JSON Getting sub key

Tags: php, json

This is my code and from my understanding this should work...
I just want to get the first url each time.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://reddit.com/r/wallpapers/.json");
$json_a=json_decode($json);
$new1 = $json_a->data->children->data[0]->url;
echo $new1;
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$new1 = $json_a->data->children->data[0]->url;` you should write `$new1 = $json_a->data->children[0]->data->url;` because children is the array, not data.

Comment: I have. I now also understand just a little bit more about how to use it.